# Check EF before changing view or URL MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I need check my EF or values of certains data before changing view or url inside the app

I have a view where process import information to other wiew under controller, i need to check values before user changing to other view or want try other process inside the view (import information)

i will try under my button inside the view but is the user want change to other view the process not work...

The process under the button is this:

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? page, string filter, int id = 0)
    {
        ViewBag.OrderPurchaseID = id;

        var check_import = db.OrderPurchaseDetails.Where(o => o.OrderPurchaseID == id && o.QtyTraslate > 0).ToList();
        if (check_import.Count() > 0)
        {
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "You have articles pending to import, check or delete them";
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "OrderPurchase", new { id = id });
        }

        #region remember filter stuff
        if (filter == "clear")
        {
            Session["Text"] = null;
            Session["From"] = null;
            Session["To"] = null;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((Session["Text"] != null) || (Session["From"] != null) || (Session["To"] != null))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Search", new { text = Session["Text"], from = Session["From"], to = Session["To"] });
            }
        }
        #endregion

        var orderpurchases = db.OrderPurchases.Include(o => o.Provider);
        int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0;
        return View(orderpurchases.OrderByDescending(p => p.TimeStamp).ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize));
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("List", "Index", new { id = Model.OrderPurchaseID }, new { @class = "btn" })
```

I need replicate this method to global level, if is possible of course...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can create a base controller that does the checking, and change all controllers to inherits from that new base controller

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean? Like @YuliamChandra mentioned you could make a base controller for global requests. Do you actually want to check/qualify data passed in from the user before redirecting them or from EF? If they have pending articles to import redirect them to a view which handles that, and then forward them on to the original requested view once complete.

Comment: Thanks you, i use LogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute OnActionExecuting, thanks you again @Lee.Winter

Comment: Thanks you, i use LogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute OnActionExecuting, thanks you again @YuliamChandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use LogAttribute to check data in my EF from import data, thanks to Yuliam and Lee Winter for the help and bring me a solution global level.

```
public class LogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private dbcAmerica db = new dbcAmerica();
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        int data = Convert.ToInt32(filterContext.Controller.TempData["id"]);
        var checkIn = db.OrderPurchaseDetails.Where(o => o.QtyTraslate > 0 && o.OrderPurchaseID == data).ToList();
        if (checkIn.Count() > 0)
        {                
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                               new RouteValueDictionary 
                               {
                                   { "action", "Edit" },
                                   { "controller", "OrderPurchase" },
                                   { "id", data},
                               });
        }
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // ... log stuff after execution
    }
}
```

Comment: the solution @YuliamChandra, thenks for your help.